# Varying Vagrant Vagrants switching wordpress-trunk to git

Tags: wordpress, git, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to convert Varying Vagrant Vagrant's `wordpress-trunk` (or development) site to be provisioned via git instead of svn.

There seems to be a script (I presume it is a script even though it has no file extension) as part of the VVV project that will switch after the machine has been provisioned:

https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/blob/master/config/homebin/develop_git

And the author told me that running the following from command line should do it:

`vagrant ssh -c "develop_git"`

but when I run that I get the following error:

> Unknown cipher type 'develop_git'

There appears to be some code in the provision script that mentions git, but I have no idea what I am looking at.

So, does anyone know how to run/implement that script? Or otherwise convert the `www/wordpress-trunk` folder to git? Are there options somewhere to direct VVV to provision the trunk folder from git in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the Vagrant-Documentation of [`vagrant ssh`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html) the `-c` option is delivered to the [`ssh`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1) command and therefore interpreted as the cipher-specification.

I would suggest you to try `vagrant ssh -- "develop_git"`, since everything after "`--` (two hyphens)[is] passed directly into the ssh executable".

Comment: Thank you! That solves this question, though I feel like I have a gazillion more to go to get everything sorted with Vagrant.